# Sed commands not working in shell script while they do one a time via ssh

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have 3 lines of sed commands that work just fine if I type then one at a time when I ssh into my server.

If I used the bellow script it does not work and I get the following error

error

````
```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `1'
```
````

script I use

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i '1d' special_pricelist.txt 
sed -i $'1 i\\\nomada\tkatigoria\tmanufacturer\tcode\tdescription\tpartno\tavailability\ttimi\tforosana\tlianiki' special_pricelist.txt 
sed 's/[\t]\{1,\}/;/g' special_pricelist.txt > file.csv
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So which line is causing the error? `do one a time via ssh` what `sed` do you have? What is the output of `sed --version`?

Comment: Please change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` and try again.

Comment: sed -i $'1 i\\\nom ..... doesn't look right. The single quote is in the wrong place.

Comment: The point is all of them work if I use them one at a time
I also tried /bin/bash and still got the same error.

Comment: @KamilCuk that is 4.4. As I mention above all the commands work if I type them one by one

Comment: Change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`. `$'...'` could be invalid in `/bin/sh`. `that is 4.4` What is "4.4"? Which implementation of `sed` do you use - GNU sed or BSD sed?

Comment: It is GNU sed both sh and bash produce the same error

Comment: The first 2 sed commands substitute line 1. Why not use `sed -e '1s/.*/wot\tevr\tstuff/'`

Comment: How exactly are you running the script? Are you sending it over the ssh connection, or does it exist on the remote system & you're just sending a command to run it? Please show exactly what you run to execute it.